# Hiding bottom tabs without using tabBarVisible in react native with multiple stacks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to hide bottom tabs on certain screens without using tabBarVisible since it adds a jumpy behaivour on iOS. I am trying to achieve this with react navigation 5 using expo.

I have the following setup that i need to change:

```
import React from 'react';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';

import SearchScreen, { searchScreenOptions } from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import PropertyDetailScreen, { propertyDetialsScreenOptions } from '../screens/PropertyDetailScreen';
import FavoriteScreen, { favoriteScreenOptions } from '../screens/FavoriteScreen';
import NotificationScreen, { notificationScreenOptions } from '../screens/NotificationScreen';
import ProfileScreen, { profileScreenOptions } from '../screens/ProfileScreen';
import MyPropertiesScreen, { myPropertiesScreenOptions } from '../screens/MyPropertiesScreen';
import SettingScreen, { settingScreenOptions } from '../screens/SettingScreen';
import FeedbackScreen, { feedbackScreenOptions } from '../screens/FeedbackScreen';
import AuthScreen, { authScreenOptions } from '../screens/AuthScreen';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import IconWithBadge from '../components/BadgeCount';

const PropertyStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const FavoriteStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const NotificationStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const ProfileStackNavigator = createStackNavigator();
const PropertyTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

const defaultNavigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    headerTintColor: '#333'
}

const PropertyNavigator = () => {
    return <PropertyStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavigationOptions}>
        <PropertyStackNavigator.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={searchScreenOptions} />
        <PropertyStackNavigator.Screen name="PropertyDetail" component={PropertyDetailScreen} options={propertyDetialsScreenOptions} />
    </PropertyStackNavigator.Navigator>
}

const FavoriteNavigator = () => {
    return <FavoriteStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavigationOptions}>
        <FavoriteStackNavigator.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteScreen} options={favoriteScreenOptions} />
        <FavoriteStackNavigator.Screen name="PropertyDetail" component={PropertyDetailScreen} options={propertyDetialsScreenOptions} />
    </FavoriteStackNavigator.Navigator>
}

const NotificationNavigator = () => {
    return <NotificationStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavigationOptions}>
        <NotificationStackNavigator.Screen name="Notification" component={NotificationScreen} options={notificationScreenOptions} />
    </NotificationStackNavigator.Navigator>
}

const ProfileNavigator = () => {
    return <ProfileStackNavigator.Navigator screenOptions={defaultNavigationOptions}>
        <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={profileScreenOptions} />
        <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen name="Feedback" component={FeedbackScreen} options={feedbackScreenOptions} />
        <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen name="MyProperty" component={MyPropertiesScreen} options={myPropertiesScreenOptions} />
        <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthScreen} options={authScreenOptions} />
        <ProfileStackNavigator.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingScreen} options={settingScreenOptions} />
    </ProfileStackNavigator.Navigator>
}

const propertyTabNavigatorOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Keresés',
    tabBarColor: '#3797dd'
}

const favoriteTabNavigatorOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Kedvencek',
    tabBarColor: '#3797dd'
}

const notificationTabNavigatorOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Értesítések',
    tabBarColor: '#3797dd'
}

const profileTabNavigatorOptions = {
    tabBarLabel: 'Profil',
    tabBarColor: '#3797dd'
}

const tabBarOptions = {
    activeTintColor: Colors.white,
    inactiveTintColor: Colors.white,
    showIcon: true,
    style: {height: 55},
    inactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    activeBackgroundColor: Colors.primary
}

const tabBarScreenOptions = ({ route }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => {
        let iconName;
        let size;
        focused ? size = 28 : size = 25;

        if (route.name === 'Search') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-search' : 'ios-search';
        } else if (route.name === 'Favorite') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-heart-empty' : 'ios-heart-empty';
        } else if (route.name === 'Notification') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-mail' : 'ios-mail';
        } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            iconName = focused ? 'ios-contact' : 'ios-contact';
        }

        if (route.name === 'Notification') {
            return <IconWithBadge name={iconName} badgeCount={3} color={color} size={size}/>
        } else {
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
        }
    },
})

const TabNavigator = () => {
    return <NavigationContainer>
        <PropertyTabNavigator.Navigator initialRouteName="Search" tabBarOptions={tabBarOptions} screenOptions={tabBarScreenOptions}>
            <PropertyTabNavigator.Screen name="Search" component={PropertyNavigator} screenOptions={propertyTabNavigatorOptions} />
            <PropertyTabNavigator.Screen name="Favorite" component={FavoriteNavigator} screenOptions={favoriteTabNavigatorOptions} />
            <PropertyTabNavigator.Screen name="Notification" component={NotificationNavigator} screenOptions={notificationTabNavigatorOptions} />
            <PropertyTabNavigator.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileNavigator} screenOptions={profileTabNavigatorOptions} />
        </PropertyTabNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
}

export default TabNavigator;
```

What i am trying to achieve is that on the following screens: PropertyDetailScreen, FeedbackScreen, MyPropertyScreen, AuthScreen, SettingsScreen i want to hide bottom tabs.

I have tried to nest my TabNavigator  into the stacks but the whole app froze. I found an explanation in the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/) but this only covers one stack. I tried to implement the given idea into multiple stacks but as i mentioned the whole app froze.

If anyone could light the beacon what i am missing would be much appreaciated.

Thanks,
Trix

Comment: Why do you need multiple stacks? Don't use navigators to organize code https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#best-practices-when-nesting

Comment: Well that part of the docs just went under my nose. Thanks for pointing it out. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
const tabBarOptions = (route) {
  activeTintColor: Colors.white,
  inactiveTintColor: Colors.white,
  showIcon: true,
  style: {height: 55},
  inactiveBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
  activeBackgroundColor: Colors.primary,
  tabBarVisible: getTabBarVisible(route),
}

const getTabBarVisible = route => {
  if (route.state?.index === 1) {
   return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```